# Android menu xml file causing error "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: android, xml

I am working through the tutorial on the android developer site.

whenever I add this item to the xml file it generaates an error:

```
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

everyelse seems to be fine. if I remove that item the errors go away and if I add it again the errors come back. I have typed it in copy and pasted it. nothing works.

Previously, I had passed that section without a problem up until I added the onOptionSelection function. When I got an error there I worked my way back until the I emptied out the xml file and got no errors. when I added the items back to the xml file then I got errors. However this item can be added to the file with no erros:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

Anyone knows what may be cause this problem

Comment: Thanks for all the comments so far. I have tried restarting eclipse. I have tried cleaning the project. nothing seems to work. I that gradle option available in eclipse. I somewhat understand the R issue because I read alot of info before I decided to post.

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and try again.  If it doesn't work, save, restart.  If all else fails try checking this site http://blog.burnayev.com/2009/11/android-developer-tip-regenerating.html.

This issue is caused due to the R files not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

restarting our android studio or java application help. You cant also try to sync project files with gradle file.

should be uder tools --> android -->  sync project files with gradle file in your android studio.

Comment: Is this gradle option available in eclipse?

Comment: i don't think so but you can restart, clean and rebuild your application in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Usually these kind of errors are indeed caused by an erroneous layout definition, but they are not the only one known issues, it could also be your Manifest file.

Your layout seems ok to me, but there's even the possibility they actually are but you need to clean your project (you'd need to select your `Project` in your WorkSpace view, and select `Project -> Clean...` within the menu. If this doesn't help, try closing/reopening Eclipse, and if this doesn't help, probably the best thing you can do is start over because as you're just starting with `Android`, there's something messed up with some attempts you might have done before.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in the past and I found out for some reason eclipse automatically added android.R to my imports. I just deleted it and cleaned my project and it fixed itself.